# Why does the `layout` I set lost its configuration after plotting a raster layer?

Tags: r, layout, raster, r-sp

I am doing an arrange of four maps for a report. My desire plots' design is this:
[image]

To do this, I use `layout()` and `plot` following guidelines [here](https://www.benjaminbell.co.uk/2018/02/creating-multi-panel-plots-and-figures.html).

I share below the code I am using to get what I mentioned. Note: code for plots 1 and 2 is simplified in order to focus on my question.

First, I design my arrange of plots:

```
## Layout design ####

layout(mat = matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                      3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4),
                    ncol = 8, byrow=TRUE), 
       widths = c(1, 1, 1),
       heights = c(1))
par(mar = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5),oma = c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5))          
    
layout.show(4) # With this command we see the current plots' design, which gives the same plot I shared previously.
```

Then, I start to plot:

```
## Set colours for maps ####

col.t <- "#D2B48C" # Coastal line colour
col.amp <- c("darkolivegreen2", "olivedrab") # Marine protected area colour
col.mar <- "lightskyblue" # Sea colour

## First plot ####

plot(1, xlim = xlim.1, ylim = ylim.1, axes = FALSE, ann = FALSE)
rect(xleft = par("usr")[1], xright = par("usr")[2], ybottom = par("usr")[3], ytop = par("usr")[4], col = col.mar, border = "transparent")
plot(coastal_line, add = TRUE, col = col.t) #shape file

## Second plot ####

plot(1, xlim = xlim.2, ylim = ylim.2, axes = FALSE, ann = FALSE)
rect(xleft = par("usr")[1], xright = par("usr")[2], ybottom = par("usr")[3], ytop = par("usr")[4], col = col.mar, border = "transparent")
plot(coastal_line, add = TRUE, col = col.t) #shape file

## Third plot ####

plot(1, xlim = xlim.3, ylim = ylim.3, axes = FALSE, ann = FALSE)
rect(xleft = par("usr")[1], xright = par("usr")[2], ybottom = par("usr")[3], ytop = par("usr")[4], col = col.mar, border = "transparent")

plot(bathymetry, 
     col = fields::tim.colors(50), 
     xlim = c(par("usr")[1], par("usr")[2]), 
     ylim = c(par("usr")[3], par("usr")[4]),
     add=TRUE,
     legend=FALSE)  #raster file
```

So far, everything is ok and my arrange of plots look like this:
[image]

However, when I add the isobaths I get problems:

```
contour(bathymetry, 
        add = TRUE, 
        levels = seq(0, -80, -8))
```

[image]

As you can see, the isobaths are plotted in a small region of my arrange of plots (in the left below corner). If I use `layout.show(n)`, I see the current arrange of plots design.

```
layout.show(16) # Here I use 16 because I checked that I had 16 plots in my layout
```

[image]

So, I don't know why, but after plotting the raster layer, my `layout` configuration (4 plots in a 2x2 matrix) has changed to a 2x8 matrix (=16 plots).

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Thanks in advance